# Where does $\cos z$ conjugate is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I solved this question using Cauchy-Riemann equations and got a contradiction,meaning not analytic everywhere, but I am not sure I am right. Got from 1 equation $x=\pi k$ from the other $x=\pi/2+\pi k$ and $y=0$. Am I right ?

Comment: The question in your title does not make sense. I suggest correcting spelling and grammar errors.

Comment: I meant Holomorphic, that is analytic function in the complex plain. And z conjugate defined to be z conj= x-iy

Comment: The standard notation for $z$ conjugate is $\overline z$. So, are you asking about $\cos(\overline z)$, or about $\overline{\cos(z)}$?

Comment: @LeeMosher: does that really matter? :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Heh, I suppose not, but perhaps what I really meant to say is "So, are you asking about $\cos(\bar z) = \overline{\cos(z)}$?" >.>

Comment: It really is the same function...

Comment: I know that is how you notate it but I don't know how to use this notation.